# Partition the set of positive real number into pairs without axiom of choice?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axiom-of-choice

*Backround.* Yesterday I made a comment on Achuille hui's answer and then I discuss on the chat with Paul Plummer about the way to partition the set of positive real number into pairs $\Bbb{R}^+=\bigcup_{i\in I}\{u_i,v_i\}$. It seems that the axiom of choice is 'needed'. Unfortunately I don't feel comfortable with it.

> **Question:** Is it possible to avoid axiom of choice to construct such a partition ?

Comment: Pair up elements of $[0,1)$ with elements of $[1,2)$ ( $(x, x+1)$). Then elements of  $[2,3)$ with elements of $[3,4)$. Etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No axiom of choice is needed.

First of all, being able to partition something into pairs is not dependent on the actual set, just its cardinality. Namely, if we can partition $\mathcal P(\Bbb N)$ into pairs, and we can prove there is a bijection between $\Bbb R^+$ and $\mathcal P(\Bbb N)$, then it gives us a partition of $\Bbb R^+$ into pairs.

And indeed we can do both these things without the axiom of choice. Partitioning $\mathcal P(\Bbb N)$ is easy. Simply consider $\{A,B\}$ such that $A\cup B=\Bbb N$ and $A\cap B=\varnothing$. Showing there is a bijection between the two sets is also not difficult, by noting that the proof of the Cantor-Bernstein is not using the axiom of choice, and that Dedekind cuts and the Cantor set define the two needed injections.

(Alternatively, you can just partition $\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$ into pairs in the obvious way, and use the fact that $\Bbb R^+$ and $\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$ have the same cardinality again, which might be a bit easier to prove.)

---

Having said that, it is consistent that there are sets which cannot be partitioned into pairs. For example in Cohen's first model there exists an infinite Dedekind-finite set of reals.

Little known is the fact that in that model, given that set, every partition into finite parts is co-finitely made of singletons. Therefore you cannot partition this set into pairs.

Comment: For $\mathbb R$ yet another alternative, maybe the easiest of all, is to define $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ by setting$$f(x)=x+(-1)^{\lfloor x\rfloor}=x+\cos(\lfloor x\rfloor\pi)$$and observe that$$f(f(x))=x\ne f(x).$$

Comment: @bof: That's pretty nice. I don't know about easiest to define, though.